# weird double pointer updating memory location

Tags: c, memory, garbage, double-pointer

I'm running the below code to store a 2D square matrix. The code reads each line, splits the elements by space and stores them to a respective cell of the matrix.

**Input format:**

The first line contains a single integer ***n***, denoting the number of rows and columns in the matrix . 
The next  lines denote the matrix 's rows, with each line containing  space-separated integers describing the columns.

**Sample Input/Input used to test**:

```
5
11 2 4 2 3
4 5 6 -1 0
10 8 -12 8 7
1 2 4 -2 5
10 -2 1 0 2
```

**Program:**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printMatrix(int n, int **matrix){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);    
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}

int main(){
    int size,length;
    int **matrix,j;
    char *buff=malloc(1000),*token;    
    fgets(buff,1000,stdin);
    sscanf(buff,"%d",&size);
    matrix=malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

        //Allocating memory for all the cells in ith row
        matrix[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*size);    
        buff='\0';
        buff=malloc(1000);
        fgets(buff,1000,stdin);
        length=strlen(buff);    
        if ((buff[length-1])=='\n'){
            buff[length-1]='\0';
        }

        j=0;
        token=strtok(buff," ");
        while(token){
            matrix[i][j]=atoi(token);
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        printMatrix(i+1,matrix);


    }
    return 0;    
}
```

**Recieved Output**:

```
11 

11 2 
4 5 

11 2 4 
4 5 6 
10 8 -12 

11 2 4 2 
4 5 6 -1 
10 8 -12 8 
1 2 4 -2 


869149824 22073 4 2 3 
4 5 6 -1 0 
10 8 -12 8 7 
1 2 4 -2 5 
10 -2 1 0 2
```

However, after 4th iteration, I'm getting garbage values 869149824 22073. I don't understand how the 1st row is getting modified.

I understand I might be making a silly mistake but I've spent quite some time figuring out what's missing here.I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `matrix=malloc(sizeof(int)*size)`... What happens if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` (like it usually is on 64-bit systems)?

Comment: `matrix=malloc(sizeof(int*)*size);`

Comment: And why do you dynamically allocate memory for `buff`? Especially since you have plenty of problems with that allocation (overwriting the pointer and memory leaks).

Comment: A good idiom to use is `var = malloc((sizeof *var) * size);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you! Perhaps you should write it as a solution. I didn't realize size of int and int* is different on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the opportunity to edit and clean up your program, your problem with the garbage prints were as previously stated caused by your memory management.

Here is the updated version of your program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printMatrix(int size, int i, int **matrix) {
    printf("\n");

    for (int y = 0; y <= i; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // turn of buffering of stdout for debug.

    int size;
    int **matrix, j;

    char buff[1000], *token;
    fgets(buff, 1000, stdin);
    buff[strcspn(buff, "\r\n")] = '\0';
    sscanf(buff, "%d", &size);

    // allocate matrix
    matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fgets(buff, 1000, stdin);
        buff[strcspn(buff, "\r\n")] = '\0';
        j = 0;
        token = strtok(buff, " ");
        while (token) {
            matrix[i][j] = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            j++;
        }
        printMatrix(size, i, matrix);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The major differences are:

- static allocation of `buff`
- Allocate all the memory needed before entering the scan loop.
- Change the print function to print the matrix row by row.

Comment: Could you please explain why using scanf is better than fgets? As far as I know, there are a lot of problems with scanf like buffer overflow, dealing with the way user responds to an input (how do you restrict or detect if a user has typed page down, return or some weird key).

Comment: You are correct, I will edit my answer, the better way to deal with trailing new lines would probably be:

fgets(buff, 1000, stdin);
buff[strcspn(buff, "\r\n")] = '\0';

Comment: strcspn() counts characters leading up to any character matched from the "stopset" ("\r\n").